# Trying to start Ruby on Rails app with Postgresql --noob

Tags: ruby, postgresql

This is my 3rd day in a row trying to start a new app using Postgresql w/ Ruby on rails with wsl ubuntu.....(i'm on windows)

I'm a beginner. I've learned the basic syntax, but getting a practice app running on Postgres i just cant seem to do it. ill literally pay for help if someone can help me out.

Everytime i try to start the database i get

```
chronokross@DESKTOP-V7DS5HD:/mnt/c/code/nathantest$ rake db:create
Database 'chrono_development' already exists
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'chrono_test' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
chronokross@DESKTOP-V7DS5HD:/mnt/c/code/nathantest
```

I've followed millions of guides. I dont know how to connect postgresql on windows to my ubunix server ROR app.

my discord is ChronoKross#1560.

```
They say to edit my databse yml file. This is how i did it

# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: chrono_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  username: chronokross

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: *****

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: chrono_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: chrono_production

  username: chronokross
  password: *****
```

PLEASE PLEASE I BEG FOR HELP. I've been studying 8hrs a day but this is a HUGE road block, i need someone to tell me what to do in noob terms or screenshare with me.

again my discord is ChronoKross#1560

Comment: Do you have postresql installed and running on your computer?

Comment: Yes. I installed it with the windows installer, but i dont thin the wsl is communicating to it? It came with pgAdmin4 this is the exact guide i followed, everything worked until i got to the rake db create part https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby-rbenv

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to just install Postgres in WSL with apt-get and then launch it  with `sudo pgcluster main 12 start`. For username you can use the default `postgres` (no password) or just setup a PG user with the same name as you shell user (whoami).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database

Comment: I follwed the guide and still have the same problem. I noticed this pc is x86, and i downloaded the x64 on windows..... im lost man im lost this is my 3rd day literally spending all day on this, it's driving me insane

Comment: nvm this is a x64 windows. I have no idea what to do

Comment: also pgcluster doesnt work